# Is there a way to have HTML elements in an overflow: scroll DIV always remain on top of other elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know the title is awful, I'm not sure quite how to explain it but you can see the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/qwwhzzc3/8/

If you drag any one of the rows, you can pull it to the drop target (labeled `Test`) and the drag/drop interaction works (both items will turn green) but it's still "inside" the div and the draggable row appears underneath the drop-target when it should be above.

The problem CSS rules are:

```
.divTable{
  display: table;
  position: static;
  z-index:1000;
  width: 100%;
}
.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
  position: inherit;
  z-index:1000;
  background-color:#fff;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

I've tried messing around with all variations of position to get this to work but I'm left scratching my head. If I do something like absolute, the styling is ruined. Relative and static do nothing. Is there a way to pull that row "out" of the scrolling container so that it can be the topmost element on the screen?

E: I know this is caused by overflow: scroll, I want to keep that and find some workaround so that I can have both behaviors

Comment: Take a look at how your HTML is updated as you drag and drop a selected line using Chrome's Inspect function. That may give you some helpful information on the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just set `position: absolute;` on the element to pull it out of its parent's containment while dragging it?  It will remove the row from the table (collapse the row's vertical space) while you are dragging it, but that may actually be a feature, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

In the event, I've create a [modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ob1934p7/34/) that temporarily inserts a placeholder element to maintain the table shape while dragging; removing it would be trivial.

The only part that's a bit of a hack is temporarily using the parent's (table's) clientWidth to set an explicit width on the row while dragging it, since while the row is positioned absolutely it won't get that sizing information from the table anymore.

Comment: Amazing, can't thank you enough for this. I can't believe I didn't think to try that, I'll have to monkey with it a bit to get it looking nice but this is the exact behavior I was hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

**edit** (snippet updated and jsfiddle too https://jsfiddle.net/qwwhzzc3/7/

your problem seems to be a matter of `z-index`, you can set it while dragging your element:

target.style.zindex = '1000'

**end edit**

You may take a look at `position:sticky;` and its javascript polyfill. *( see this article to dig further https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/ )*

pure CSS example:

```js
const startPos = { x: 0, y: 0 }

const moveListener = e => {
  const target = e.target
  const x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0)
  const y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0)
  const transX = x + e.dx
  const transY = y + e.dy
  target.style.webkitTransition = '-webkit-transform 0ms'
  target.style.transition = 'transform 0ms'
  target.style.webkitTransform = `translate(${transX}px, ${transY}px`
  target.style.transform = `translate(${transX}px, ${transY}px`
  target.setAttribute('data-x', transX)
  target.setAttribute('data-y', transY)
}

const dragdrop = () => {
 interact('.draggable')
  .on('dragstart', e => {
   const target = e.target
    startPos.x = parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0
    startPos.y = parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0
  })
  .draggable({
    inertia: false,
    autoScroll: true,
    onmove: moveListener,
    onend: e => {
     const target = e.target
      target.style.webkitTransition = '-webkit-transform 333ms'
      target.style.transition = 'transform 333ms'
      target.style.webkitTransform = `translate(${startPos.x}px, ${startPos.y}px`
      target.style.transform = `translate(${startPos.x}px, ${startPos.y}px`
      target.style.zindex = '1000'
      target.setAttribute('data-x', startPos.x);
      target.setAttribute('data-y', startPos.y);
    }
  })
  interact('.dropRow').dropzone({
    accept: '.draggable',
    overlap: 0.7,
    ondragenter: e => {
      e.target.classList.add('drop-target')
      e.relatedTarget.classList.add('drop-target')
    },
    ondragleave: e => {
      e.target.classList.remove('drop-target')
      e.relatedTarget.classList.remove('drop-target')
    },
    ondrop: e => {
      e.target.classList.remove('drop-target')
      e.relatedTarget.classList.remove('drop-target')
    }
  })
}

dragdrop()
```

```css
.divTable{
  display: table;
  position: static;
  z-index:1000;
 width: 100%;
}
.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
  position: inherit;
  z-index:1000;
  background-color:#fff;
  }
  .sticky .header {
  position:sticky;
  top:-2px;
}
.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #fff;
 display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 display: table-cell;
   padding: 3px 10px;
}
.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #fff;
 display: table-header-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
 background-color: #fff;
 display: table-footer-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
 display: table-row-group;
}
.header {
    background-color:#ccc!important;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.9/interact.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class="divTable" >
    <div class="divTableBody">
      <div class="divTableRow sticky">
        <div class="divTableCell header">Name</div>
        <div class="divTableCell header">Status</div>
        <div class="divTableCell header">Location</div>
        <div class="divTableCell header">Time On Status</div>
        <div class="divTableCell header">Weekly Hours</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow draggable">
        <div class="divTableCell">Bob</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Happy</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">California</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">10:00</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">30:00</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class='divTable'>
    <div class='divTableBody'>
      <div class='divTableRow'>
        <div class='divTableCell dropRow'>
          <span>Test</span>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Yur fiddle updated  https://jsfiddle.net/qwwhzzc3/1/

Comment: I posted the wrong fiddle thats my fault: https://jsfiddle.net/qwwhzzc3/5/ this is in a working state and has your changes but I still can't pull the row past the scroll bars

Comment: sorry for double comment but I get what you mean, I don't think sticky is what I want. I'm not worried about items within the same container, but with having the ability to pull that item out of the container with it on top instead of underneath all other elements

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak not too sure anymore of what you are looking for, but indeed, sticky seems not to it. (it sticks and remains on top of nexts scrolling untill end of its parent container scrolls up and it up too.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak okay, i saw the bug, you need to reset z-index while dragging to make sure element stands is drawn on top of its sibblings. https://jsfiddle.net/qwwhzzc3/7/ (answer updated )

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak  not okay, i think i missunderstood once more your issue , but the z-index is to keep in mind so the dragged element doesn't slide under another row .... the pagination looks like the way :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `overflow: scroll` set on the `.container` class. When setting that rule, you making it so that anything that would flow out of the container should be hidden and cause the container to scroll. Here is your updated fiddle showing what I think what you want without the scroll overflow:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qwwhzzc3/6/)

So my suggestion would be to add pagination to the table instead of scrolling. Then you could still set a static height and allow the dragged items to appear over others items in different containers.

Comment: Yeah I know that's causing the problem, I'm hoping there is a workaround. I want the container to have a fixed height, but the number of rows in the table is variable. I'm really hoping there is a way to achieve this without sacrificing that, or I'll have to make some design sacrifices elsewhere. Pagination is a good idea, that will probably be my fallback if there is no other solution